# Table View not reloading data from database

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I'm trying to reload my table view when the view loads and when the view appears. I'm pulling the data from a database so i think my issue is speed related. This function is called in my view did load and view did appear, I've tried calling `tableView.reloadData()` in various places but it doesn't load the table view with values upon loading the view. the table view does populate when the blog button is tapped though.

```
func articleRefresh(){

        DataService.instance.getAllArticles { (returnedArticlesArray) in
            self.blogArray.removeAll()
            self.newsArray.removeAll()
            self.rosterArray.removeAll()
            self.draftArray.removeAll()
            self.articleArray.removeAll()
            for article in returnedArticlesArray {

                if article.category == "blog" {

                    self.blogArray.append(article)
                }
                else if article.category == "news" {
                    self.newsArray.append(article)
                }
                else if article.category == "roster" {
                    self.rosterArray.append(article)
                }
                else if article.category == "draft" {
                    self.draftArray.append(article)
                } else {
                    self.blogArray.append(article)
                }
            }
            self.newsArray.reverse()
            self.rosterArray.reverse()
            self.draftArray.reverse()

        }

    }

@IBAction func BlogPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        articleArray.removeAll()

        self.articleArray = self.blogArray
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Comment: This code is vertiginous. Use **one** array  as data source and assign `returnedArticlesArray` to it. It will solve you problem

Comment: and then separate the arrays in viewDidLoad?

Comment: No, forget the arrays. Declare one array with the type of `article` and get all information from there. Alternatively group the array to a dictionary by `category`.

Comment: that's definitely a smarter way to do it but that still doesn't solve my problem, the issue was is wasn't downloading fast enough

Answer (score 0):

You should call `tableView.reloadData()` in the callback after your data source update.  I guess in your case it should be placed after `self.draftArray.reverse()`.

Comment: And as was commented, you should not update your data source arrays like this. Instead do all work using local variables, then update data source array for table view and reload it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use async dispatch queue , may be it's work. where  you data get just put after that.

`DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      self.tblHome.reloadData()
                    }`